# Making button click once

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT**

In my game I want my button to disable after one click but for some reason all the ways I have looked at do not work.

Here is what I have at the moment..

```
$('.minibutton').click(function() {

$(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
$('.minibutton').prop('disabled', false);
$('.picstyle').show();
$('td').removeClass('spellword');
var r = rndWord;
while (r == rndWord) {
    rndWord = Math.floor(Math.random() * (listOfWords.length));
}

$('td[data-word="' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + '"]').addClass('spellword');
$('td[data-word=' + word + ']').removeClass('wordglow').removeClass('wordglow4').removeClass('wordglow3').css('color', 'transparent');

var noExist = $('td[data-word=' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + ']').hasClass('wordglow2');
if (noExist) {
    $('.minibutton').click();

} else {

    $("#mysoundclip").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].audio);
    audio.play();
    $("#mypic").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].pic);
    jQuery(pic).show();
}


}).trigger("click");
```

I have tried changing the click function to..

```
$('.minibutton').one("click", function() {
```

I have also tried to bind and unbind it but it will not work

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Y7A5/9/

You spell the highlighted word, using the picture as a clue. If you get the word wrong 3 times you are given the opportunity to move on because "minibutton" appears. At this point I only want the user to be able to click it once before it disappears again.

Comment: You don't need to unbind it if you use the `one` function.

Comment: why dont you have a variable track the button click and change it when it gets clicked

Comment: I mean on different attempts @jessegavin

Comment: Milo-J, you're fiddle is understandably long, and the majority of us do not have time to learn how to play in order to test our solutions. Please provide some instructions regarding what one must do in your fiddle in order to replicate the issue you are having.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions. I have updated my post with the updated fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the jQuery `.on()` and `.off()` methods. In the documentation on jQuery's site, there should be a section about namespacing - this section covers what you're looking for.

Below, I have given you the solution that you are looking for, but review the documentation anyway so that you can better understand it.

First, add this variable declaration above your click-handler:

```
var timesClicked = 0;
```

Then, change your handler declaration to this:

```
$('.minibutton').on("click.oneclick", function () {...});
```

And add these lines in your handler:

```
if (timesClicked > 0) {
    $(this).off("click.oneclick");
} else {
    timesClicked++;
}
```

Basically, what's happening here is that you are giving your click-event handler a distinct name that differentiates it from all other click-event handlers on the page (that is, all other click-handlers that do not also have that namespace). You could have applied the namespace "foo" - I chose to apply the namespace "oneclick". The result is that you have the ability to remove that specific click-event handler without removing any of the other click-event handlers (that is, any others that do not have the given namespace).

Try this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Y7A5/20/) of your solution.

**UPDATE:**

To help you with your question of re-enabling the click event, first do the following (note: there are a lot of things in your code that need cleaning up, but I did point out one thing, which was an empty click handler being set to minibutton):

```
var clickOnceTest = 0;
function enableMinibutton() {
    $('.minibutton').on("click.clickOnceNS", function() {
        if (clickOnceTest > 0) {
            $(this).off("click.clickOnceNS");
        } else {
            clickOnceTest++;
        }
        $('.minibutton').prop('disabled', false);
        $('.picstyle').show();
        $('td').removeClass('spellword');
        var r = rndWord;
        while (r == rndWord) {
            rndWord = Math.floor(Math.random() * (listOfWords.length));
        }

        $('td[data-word="' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + '"]').addClass('spellword');
        $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').removeClass('wordglow').removeClass('wordglow4').removeClass('wordglow3').css('color', 'transparent');

        var noExist = $('td[data-word=' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + ']').hasClass('wordglow2');
        if (noExist) {
            /////
            /////
            /////
            /////
            /////        
            ////// Is this supposed to trigger a click? because all this does is set another click handler (which does nothing) to minibutton..
            /////
            /////
            /////
            /////
            /////
            $('.minibutton').click();

        } else {

            $("#mysoundclip").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].audio);
            audio.play();
            $("#mypic").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].pic);
            pic.show();
        }

    });
}

enableMinibutton();
$(".minibutton").trigger("click");
```

Once you've done that, when you're ready to re-enable `minibutton` all you have to do is call the method `enableMinibutton()`. If you need to call the `trigger("click")` method again, do so (I'm not exactly sure why it was there for in the first place). You can call this method either immediately before/after showing the button the second time (my preference - I don't like unnecessary handlers slowing my script down), or you can call it immediately after you hide the button.

As for the other things that need cleaning: throughout your code you have things, like the empty click handler that I pointed out, that are unnecessary, slow down your program, throw errors, or just plain don't work. Remove or comment these things out ASAP. Once you do, your code will run much smoother, and your tests/experiments will be more likely to succeed/fail properly, without influence of bad code.

Additionally, and I cannot stress this one enough, you need to set your element selectors to variables. You select `minibutton` and `minibutton2` and a bunch of other items dozens of times throughout your code. Just set their selectors to variables at the top and use said variables to refer to your elements, instead of selecting them over and over again. 
Every time you call a jQuery selector, you are essentially searching the DOM for the elements that satisfy your selector. If your collection is always going to have the same elements in it, set the selector to a variable and call on the variable instead. This way, you are only searching the DOM once for these elements. The performance difference is very noticeable in heavy-weight programs, especially in ones like this. In case you are unfamiliar with this syntax, here are two examples, using `minibutton` and `minibutton2`:

```
var $minibutton = $(".minibutton");
var $minibutton2 = $(".minibutton2");
....
$minibutton.on("click.click.......
...
$minibutton.trigger(....
...
$minibutton2.prop(...
...
```

As you can see, I like to prefix my selector variables with the `$` so that it is easier to see and remember that the variable they hold is a selected element. This is not required, and you can set the variable name to whatever you want.

The only catch to doing this is that you must "update" the variable if you plan to add more items to the DOM that would be returned by the selector; the variable will reference all elements returned by the selector AT THE TIME THE SELECTOR WAS INITIALLY CALLED. This means that if you have a collection of elements of a particular class and set a variable to refer to that collection, before adding additional elements with said class, in order to reference additional elements that would later be returned by that selector you will have to set it again. Yes, I know that was long and confusing, but it's actually pretty simple and there are dozens of examples online about it.

Comment: It breaks the button now. Have you looked at the fiddle. The button I am talking about only appears after 3 wrong attempts. Then allows you to move on to next @Zachary Kniebel

Comment: I noticed something - why do you have `.trigger("click");` at the end of your function? If you disable the button in the handler that trigger won't work

Comment: To avoid that you should use a flag variable - I'll post an update

Comment: Yeh I use that to auto click after a word is correctly completed. Thanks, do you have a fiddle? @Zachary Kniebel

Comment: Thanks but the problem is still happening. When you get 3 tries wrong the button appears and can be pressed as many times as the user wants @Zachary Kniebel

Comment: Are you talking about the button that says "Next" or some other button?

Comment: Also, what is `.minibutton2` and could that be the button that you are seeing?

Comment: Yes the next button. "minibutton2" replays the sound @Zachary Kniebel

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18724/discussion-between-milo-j-and-zachary-kniebel)

Comment: Sorry about that Milo, I added the wrong link - it has since been updated

Comment: The problem is the button only works once. Is there a way to reset it? @Zachary Kniebel

Comment: Yes,  call the '.on()'  method again and attach "click.oneclick"  again with your function body

Comment: Where exactly do I call it? @Zachary Kniebel

Comment: That depends - when do you want it to reset? After you click the "reset" button?

Comment: So I want it to reset for the next time it appear so it clicks once again. I have tried this but it doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/7Y7A5/29/ @Zachary Kniebel

Comment: Take a look at my update. The first part should tell you what you need to do.

Comment: The useless part is meant to be .prop('enable'). Have you got a fiddle? @Zachary Kniebel

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to make one. I'm responding to you during wait times. let's move this to chat

Comment: the trigger is used to move on automatically after the word is spelt correctly
the problem I am having is with resetting the clickOnceTest so it can start again for the next word @Zachary Kniebel

Comment: Milo-J - the comments here are getting too long and I do not have availability to chat with you. What you should do is clean up your code according to advice that I gave you in my update, and post a new question regarding difficulties with resetting a variable. One of the other things that I suggest that you try is making some new, smaller fiddles, with simpler examples that illustrate the issue that you are having. You can use these to try to debug your issue or include them in your new question, to keep things simpler for those providing you with solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled = true" value="Save"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use modern Js, with "disabled" or "once"!

```
button.disabled = true;
```

or

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Fire event
}, {once : true});
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/addeventlistener-once), [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=once-event-listener)